# Development testing across different version of MS word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

I am working on a project where we are creating a add-in for MS word. Right now I am testing my add-in on office 365(version 2016). But I want to test my add-in with 
older versions of MS word(2013,2007) also.

So, is there any way or mode in word app by which I can test across different versions of word (using only one word app).

If any another tool exist to do so,that also work for me.
Or I have to install all different version of word to do so?

Comment: I suspect you'll need to build it and install into each version. You might want to start by looking at reserved words, and make sure you've not used any new syntax that isn't supported in 2007.

Answer (score 2):

Maintaining compatibility across versions of MS Word is usually not that difficult if you keep one tenet in mind ... compatibility is upward and not downward.

With that in mind, generally build your solution with the oldest version of MS Word for where you expect it to run. With that said, be careful with the UI (Ribbon) because there's a difference between Word 2007 and all later versions.

If you are using VSTO to build your solution, and you are staying away from supporting Word 2007, you can easily create your solution so that it is compatible with versions 2010 all the way to the current 2019. Just include Word 14.0 in your references.

Another method that you can use is Virtual Machines. In each VM run a different Office version and install/test your solution on each.

If you are using VBA to develop your add-in, and you are interfacing Word with another Office application such as Excel or PowerPoint ... remember that compatibility truth I first mentioned. A Word add-in developed under Word 2019 will resolve the library reference to other versions of Word but it won't resolve the references to other versions of Excel or PowerPoint that you may be using.

For example, if you have a VBA add-in that your wrote under version 17.0 (Office 2019) and you are passing some data to PowerPoint and you have a reference in your solution to PowerPoint 17.0 ... if you attempt to run your solution on a system with Office 2010, Word will resolve to version 14.0 automatically, and you will get a runtime error telling you it can't find PowerPoint 17.0. There are ways around this and one of which is before you distribute, compile the solution on a machine with Office 2010. Another, is to become versed with the terms & techniques of, "Early Binding and Late Binding."